# Dependency Property meta throws error when resolved by Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism, dependency-properties

I have a presentationmodel(viewmodel) containing a dependencyy property registered as below..

```
public Field SelectedField
{
    get { return (Field)GetValue(SelectedFieldProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(SelectedFieldProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFieldProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedField", typeof(Field), typeof(PresentationModel), new PropertyMetadata(new  PropertyChangedEventHandler(onPropertyChangedSelectedField)));

private static void onPropertyChangedSelectedField(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I am resolving the view from a controller like below..

```
 IPresentationModel presenter = this.Container.Resolve<IPresentationModel>();
```

While trying to do, I am getting an error mentioning - Exception occurred while: Calling constructor PresentationModel, when digged in, I noticed that the error is occuring in the below line..

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFieldProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedField", typeof(Field), typeof(PresentationModel), new PropertyMetadata(new  PropertyChangedEventHandler(onPropertyChangedSelectedField)));
```

I Identified that the error is due to PropertyChangedEventHandler and DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler when mentioned in propertymeta data, However, for PropertyChangedCallBack I don't face any error and view is loaded fine. What would be the problem in this..

Comment: What is the Field type? Has it a public constructor? And watch out, you are firing an NotImplementedException in the property changed delegate.

Comment: Field is set to private constructor.. I have even tried the same to changing to public constructor..Same exception. Not Implemented exception should not cause this since the flow doesn't go till there..I have commented the exception and tried.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the MSDN documentation it seems that [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [PropertyChangedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are used for different things.

According to the documentation the **PropertyChangedCallback** is what I believe you are looking for:

> *"Represents the callback that is invoked when the effective property value of a **dependency property** changes."*

As for the **PropertyChangedEventHandler** the documentation says:

> *"Represents the method that will handle the **PropertyChanged** event raised* (from the INotifyPropertyChanged interface) *when a property is changed on a component."*

This seems to hint that this delegate is used to be notified of changes in common properties, like when a view has a binding to a property in its view model. Therefore, these two delegates doesn't seem to be "exchangeable" (they are even defined in different namespaces.)

Comment: Thank you, But It shouldn't throw me error when I use 'PropertyChangedEventHandler' right?